# unable to read tiff with lzw compression for jai codec api

Tags: compression, lzw

I am unable to read tiff file by using jai codec API which is having LZW compression technique.

The below lines I am using to render tiff image.

PlanarImage pImage = new NullOpImage(renderedImage, null, null, OpImage.OP_IO_BOUND);
firstImage = pImage.getAsBufferedImage();

Exceptions are the below.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The input argument(s) may not be null.
at javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.wrapRenderedImage(PlanarImage.java:582)
at javax.media.jai.NullOpImage.<init>(NullOpImage.java:108)
```

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.TIFFLZWDecoder.addStringToTable(TIFFLZWDecoder.java:180)
    at com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.TIFFLZWDecoder.decode(TIFFLZWDecoder.java:109)
    at com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.TIFFImage.getTile(TIFFImage.java:1565)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedImageAdapter.getTile(RenderedImageAdapter.java:156)
    at javax.media.jai.NullOpImage.computeTile(NullOpImage.java:170)
    at com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler.scheduleTile(SunTileScheduler.java:912)
    at javax.media.jai.OpImage.getTile(OpImage.java:1139)
    at javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.copyData(PlanarImage.java:2356)
    at javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.getAsBufferedImage(PlanarImage.java:2538)
    at javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.getAsBufferedImage(PlanarImage.java:2559)

please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but hopefully this will help someone in the future... I was only able to resolve this issue by manually downloading the JAI JARs as well as libclib_jiio.so found here https://github.com/roundwheel/photomosaic/tree/master/PhotoMosaicCore/lib/jai, and referencing those JARs directly in my project pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.media.jai</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.media.jai.core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jai/jai_core.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.media.jai</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.sun.media.jai.codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jai/jai_codec.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.media.imageio</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.sun.media.imageio</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jai/jai_imageio.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>clibwrapper_jiio</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jai/clibwrapper_jiio.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

The problem seems to be that the clibwrapper_jiio JAR is missing from the Maven repository (click "Download JAR" here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.media/clibwrapper_jiio/1.1).